# Pad batches with random integers in Tensorflow Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset on which I am training a model using negative sampling. Each example has some IDs with it corresponding to some fixed negative samples that will be used.

In addition to the fixed negative samples, I would like to include random negative samples. However, each example has a variable number of fixed negative samples, so I need to append a variable number of random IDs. This is essentially the function performed by the `padded_batch` function, but I need to pad with random integers from some range instead.

Is there a way to accomplish this through the Tensorflow Python API or do I need to write a custom Dataset class in C++?